# getBindingContext() is undefined

Tags: sapui5

I'm making a little program for a school assignment, but I encounter a problem. 
I need to make a program in SAPUI5 that loads JSON data in a table. On each row there is a function (`onItemSelected`) attached. So when I press on a row, I need to get the ID of the weekday.

This is how the program looks like now:

[image: Current state]

When I press on a row, it says that my `getBindingContext()` is undefined.

[image: alert of getBindingContext() being undefined]

#### In my index.html

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function(){
  var oWeekdagModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
  oWeekdagModel.loadData("./model/weekdagen.json");
  sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oWeekdagModel, "week");
});
var oResourceModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
  bundleName : "sap.ui.demo.db.i18n.i18n"
});
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oResourceModel, "i18n");
new sap.ui.core.mvc.XMLView({
  viewName: "sap.ui.demo.db.view.App"
}).placeAt("content");
```

#### App.view.xml

```xml
<mvc:View
  xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  controllerName="sap.ui.demo.db.controller.App"
>
  <Table id="idWeekdagenTable"
    inset="false"
    items="{week>/weekdays}"
  >
    <headerToolbar>
      <!-- ... -->
    </headerToolbar>
    <columns>
      <Column width="20%">
        <Text text="Id" />
      </Column>
      <Column width="20%">
        <Text text="Weekdag" />
      </Column>
      <Column width="20%">
        <Text text="Aantal gewoon eten" />
      </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
      <ColumnListItem
        press=".onItemSelected"
        type="Active"
      >
        <Text id="id" text="{week>id}" />
        <Text id="day" text="{week>day}" />
        <Text text="{week>no_meals}" />
      </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
  </Table>
  <Table id="idMaaltijdenTable"
    inset="false"
    items="{maaltijd>/meals}"
  >
    <headerToolbar>
      <!-- ... -->
    </headerToolbar>
    <columns>
      <Column width="20%">
        <Text text="Maaltijd" />
      </Column>
      <Column width="20%">
        <Text text="Descriptie"/>
      </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
      <ColumnListItem
        press=".onItemSelected"
        type="Active"
      >
        <Text text="{maaltijd>MealNo}" />
        <Text text="{maaltijd>items}" />
      </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
  </Table>
</mvc:View>
```

#### App.controller.js

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller){
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.db.controller.App", {
    onInit: function() {
      var oWeekdagModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
      oWeekdagModel.loadData("weekdagen.json");
      //binding op view
      sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oWeekdagModel);
    },

    onItemSelected: function(oEvent) {
      var oItem, oCtx;
      oItem = oEvent.getSource();
      oCtx = oItem.getBindingContext();
      alert(oCtx); // is undefined
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the binding context of clicked item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556515/how-to-get-the-binding-context-of-clicked-item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull out the day's ID from the model using binding path. Here is a relevant part of your `onItemSelected()` function:

```js
...
oCtx = oItem.getBindingContext();
var oPressedItem = sap.ui.getCore().getModel().getProperty(oCtx.getPath());
...
```

and then `oPressedItem.id` will give you the ID of the day from the top table and `oPressedItem.dayId` - from the bottom table.

[Here](https://jsbin.com/wewidukifi/2/edit?html,output) is a working example.