# How to get the binding context of clicked item?

Tags: sapui5

I have a [List](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.List) that looks as follows:

[image: screenshot of sap.m.List in UI5]

The code regarding to `List`:

View:

```xml
<List id="navigation"
  itemPress=".handleItemPress"
  items="{ac>/YGAC_C_JOB_PROFILE}"
>
  <StandardListItem
    type="Navigation"
    press=".handleListPress"
    title="{ac>Description}"
  />
</List>
```

Event handler:

```js
handleItemPress: function (oEvent) {
  // console.log(oEvent.getSource().getMetadata().getName());
  // console.log(oEvent.getSource().getSelectedItem());
},

handleListPress: function (oEvent) {
  console.log(oEvent.getSource().getObjectBinding()); // returns null
  console.log(oEvent.getSource().getBinding());  // returns null
  console.log(oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext());  // returns null
},
```

What am I trying to achieve is, when I press on an item in the list, for instance "Division Switzerland", I would like to get the bound context. As you can see on the view, the `List` is bound to an OData service.

With UI5 browser tool, you can see, that the `List` is bound to a context:

[image: Screenshot of the UI5 inspector extension]

How to get the bound context from the clicked item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both APIs [`getObjectBinding`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.ListBase#events/itemPress) and [`getBindingContext`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject#methods/getBindingContext) await a model name as an argument. I.e. in your case, it should be:

```js
handleItemPress: function(event) {
  const clickedItem = event.getParameter("listItem");
  const context = clickedItem.getBindingContext(/*modelName*/"ac"); // given items="{ac>...}"
},
```